# Jenkins Email Notification and GIT

Tags: git, email, jenkins, groovy

I'm new to Jenkins and I need to change the content of the default email notifications such that in addition to the default message they'll also show the GIT_AUTHOR and GIT_MESSAGE and possible some statistics about the various tests.

From my little research I understand that there are some plugins that might help me such as Email-ext plugin, Email-ext Template Plugin, Git Changelog Plugin.
The concise documentation of the plugins didn't help me that much. Is there any way to achieve my goal using one of these plugins, and if so, how?
If not, I assume I should do it with Groovy. In this case, how to obtain the contents of GIT_AUTHOR and GIT_MESSAGE using Groovy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The token you can use in the email-ext plugin get dynamically extended by various plugins, see [Token Macro Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin), token producer section.

Install those git related plugins and consult the content token reference by clicking the *?* just after the Attach build log combobox at the email content configuration, if i remember correctly author and message should be aviable.

Comment: I tried email-ext plugin ${CHANGES} token with %m and %a formatting, but I'm getting "No changes" instad of the relevant changes and the name of the the committer.